# MHPagingScrollView won't scroll with own View

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I downloaded the MHPagingScrollView project and included it in my project.
With the sample code of "PageView" it worked very well.
This is a UILabel.

When I add my own view to the storyboard and change the sample to

```
- (UIView *)pagingScrollView:(MHPagingScrollView *)thePagingScrollView pageForIndex:  (NSUInteger)index
  {
WBContentViewController *pageView = (WBContentViewController *)[thePagingScrollView dequeueReusablePage];
if (pageView == nil) {
    pageView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentView"];
}

return pageView.view;
}
```

I can see my view, but it's not scrollable.
This view has a fixed size.

Does anybody has an idea for that issue?

EDIT:
I noticed, that I can scroll vom the left edge of the scrollview. When I try to scroll fast to the left, the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

changing "Autolayout" to off solved my problem.